# ElasticSearch - Adding a new parameter with conditions by using script_fields

Tags: elasticsearch

The logic: add a parameter to show products that the current user like this product for `Front-end` to process. (the parameter of the `user_id` will be required)

Mapping method:

```
{"mappings": { "properties": {
                              "name_product": {"type": "text"},
                              "price": {"type":"long"},
                              "user_who_like":{"type":"text"}
}            }               }
```

Sample data:

```
{
 "name_product": "ABC",
 "price": 320,
 "user_who_like": ["a2","a1"]    #id of people who liked this product before
}
```

The expected result:

```
 {
  "name_product": "ABC",
  "price": 320,
  "user_who_like": ["a2","a1"],
  "liked": true                   //the current user did like this product
 }

{
 "name_product": "EDF",
 "price": 320,
 "user_who_like": ["a2"],
 "liked": false                  //the current user did not like this product
}
```

My best try so far after looking up so many resources:

```
{
    "query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match_all": {}}]}}
    ,
    "script_fields": {
        "info": {
            "script": "params['_source']"
        },
        "is_like": {
            "script": {
                "params": {
                    "my_id": "a1"
                },
                "source": "if (doc['user_who_like'].size()!= 0) 
                               {
                                for (id_index in doc['user_who_like']) 
                                     {if id_index == params.my_id {return true} else {return false}
                               } 
                          else 
                               {
                                 return false
                               }"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not working and give me this error :

```
"root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "compile error",
                "script_stack": [
                    "... oc['user_who_like']) {if id_index == params.my_id  ...",
                    "                             ^---- HERE"
                ],
                "script": "if (doc['user_who_like'].size()!= 0) {for (id_index in doc['user_who_like']) {if id_index == params.my_id {return true} else {return false}} else {return false}}",
                "lang": "painless",
                "position": {
                    "offset": 81,
                    "start": 56,
                    "end": 106
                }
            }
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to wrap your `if` conditions in parentheses:

```
if id_index == params.my_id
   
   |
   |
   v

if (id_index == params.my_id)
```